# Creating an alias for a printer

Tags: cups

CUPS auto-detected the printer in the corridor and assigned to it the name

```
Xerox_WorkCentre_5775_v1_Multifunction_System
```

but I cannot use such a name with, e.g., `lpadmin` without resorting to some form of cut and paste.

Is there a command line (or, second choice, a procedure using the CUPS web interface at `localhost:631`) to have an alias so that I can say `lpadmin -p xerox -o ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class that only contains the printer of interest and
then refer to it by way of that class.

```
lpadmin -p Long_Printer_Name_2000 -c daffy
echo daffy's a nice name for a printer | lp -d daffy
```